# How to prove $\gcd(a^2,b^2) = (\gcd(a,b))^2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers

How to prove $\gcd(a^2, b^2) = (\gcd(a, b))^2$?

My attempt:

Let $\gcd(a, b) = d$.

Then $d|a$ and $d|b$ then $d^2|a^2$ and $d^2|b^2$. i.e $d^2$ divides $a^2 ~~\&~~ b^2$.

Comment: your approach is correct.

Comment: Prime factorization

Answer (score 8):

Hint: Factor $a$ and $b$ into primes. If $a=p_1^{n_1}\\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k^{n_k}$ and $b=p_1^{m_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k^{m_k}$ with each $n_i,m_i\ge 0$. Then

$$(a,b)=p_1^{\min\{n_1,m_1\}}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k^{\min\{n_k,m_k\}}.$$

Comment: Please explain in details.

Comment: If you square a number this amounts to doubling all the exponents in its prime factorization. $\min(2x,2y) = 2\min(x,y)$ so this proves it. You can prove virtually any fact about $\gcd$ using this method; it's usually much easier and more direct.

Answer (score 3):

$\begin{align}(a,b)(a^2,b^2) =&\ (a^3,a^2b,ab^2,b^3)\quad [\text{by basic gcd laws - see Remark below}]\\
=&\ (a,b)^3\end{align}$

Thus $\ (a^2,b^2) = (a,b)^2\ $ by cancelling $\,(a,b) \neq 0.\ \ $ [[See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/376412/242) for the cubic analog]

---

**Or**: Gauss's Lemma (GL) yields a slick proof. Let $\rm\:{\cal C}(f)\:$ denote the content of a polynomial, i.e. the gcd of its coefficients. Then GL $\rm\: \Rightarrow\ {\cal C}(f\:g) \color{#c00}{\overset{\rm GL_{\phantom |}\!}=}\ {\cal C}(f)\ {\cal C}(g)\ $ so

$$ (a,b)^2\! =\ {\cal C}\:(ax\! +\! b)\ {\cal C}\:(a x\! -\! b)\, \color{#c00}{\overset{\rm GL_{\phantom |}\!}=}\, {\cal C}\:((a x\! +\! b)(ax\! -\! b))\, =\, {\cal C}\:(a^2 x^2\! -\! b^2)\, =\, (a^2,b^2)\qquad$$

---

**Replying** to comments, [we used only](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3635955/242) basic gcd laws ([associative](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242) & commutative & [distributive](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/705862/242)), e.g. let's do the gcd analog of the binomial theorem (in detail)

$\ (a,b)^2\! = (a,b)(a,b) = ((a,b)a,(a,b)b) = ((a^2,ba),(ab,b^2)) = (a^2,ba,ab,b^2) = (a^2,ab,b^2)$

Similarly $\,(a,b)^3 = (a,b)(a,b)^2 = (a,b)(a^2,ab,b^2) =\,\cdots\, = (a^3,a^2b,ab^2,b^3)$

By induction $\ (a,b)^n = (a^n, a^{n-1}b,\cdots\,ab^{n-1},b^n)\ $ is straightforwardly proved.

Such gcd arithmetic requires no ingenuity, it is analogous to multiplying polynomials.

The proof generalizes to the [Freshman' Dream](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/10416/242) $\,(a,b)^n = (a^n,b^n)\,$ for gcds and invertible ideals.

Comment: How is $(a^3,a^2b,ab^2,b^3)=(a,b)^3$ any more obvious than $(a^2,b^2)=(a,b)^2$?

Comment: @Barry It's just gcd binomial expansion using basic gcd laws (associative, commutative, distributive). The latter is not "obvious" since $\,(a,b)^2 = (a^2,ab,b^2).\,$ It requires proof to show it equals $\,(a^2,b^2).\ \ $

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I was just being stoneheaded.

Comment: @Barry I elaborated a bit in a remark.

Comment: But isn't it a theorem (or lemma, if you like) in its own right that $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,ad,bc,bd)$?  It's easy enough to show, based purely on the definition of greatest common divisor, that $(a,b)(c,d)$ divides $(ac,ad,bc,bd)$.  But showing the other direction, it seems to me, requires additional work.

Comment: On further thought, it occurs to me even the "easy" direction in my previous comment requires a little lemma about gcds, namely that if $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$, then $d\mid(a,b)$.

Comment: @Barry It's not a Theorem but, rather, just a consequence of trivial gcd arithmetic. As I show in the Remark, it follows by rote gcd arithmetic using said gcd laws (most notably the gcd [Distributive Law).](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/785544/242) The calculation of $\,(a,b)^3\,$ is precisely analogous (and just as trivial) as the calculation of $\,(a+b)^3\,$ using the analogous ring laws / axioms (associative, commutative, distributive).

Comment: @Barry In fact, if you write $\,\gcd(a,b) = a\dot+b\,$ then the arithmetic looks just like ring arithmetic, except we have the additional law that $\, a\dot+ab = a.\,$ [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/810481/242) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/147992/242) for some examples.

Comment: Bill, many thanks for the additional replies.  I agree, it's all ultimately trivial gcd arithmetic, but that's sort of my point:  We don't know which, if any, of these easily proved points the OP has at his or her disposal.

Comment: @Barry The (easy) proofs of the basic gcd laws are all on MSE (and in most textbooks). But, alas, rarely do elementary textbooks emphasize the analogy with integer (ring) arithmetic. No doubt that it is difficult to judge which proofs will be most accessible to OPs, since they usually do not provide enough context to infer that.

Answer (score 2):

If $\gcd(a,b)=d$, then
$a = a'd$
$b = b'd$
and $\gcd(a',b') = 1$

That means
$a^2 = {a'}^2d^2$
$b^2  = {b'}^2d^2$
and $\gcd({a'}^2,{b'}^2) = 1$  $ ~~\color{red}{ \star }$

Hence $\gcd(a^2,b^2)=d^2$.

$ ~~\color{red}{ \star }$ pelase see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460213/prove-that-if-gcda-b-1-then-gcda2-b2-1).

Comment: Not a good solution in my opinion because you've used the fact that if $\gcd (a',b')=1$ then $\gcd(a'^2,b'^2)=1$ this is what the question asks to prove!

Comment: As $$\gcd(a,b)=d\iff \gcd({a\over d},{b\over d})=1$$

Comment: Yeah we can add that line

Comment: It seems to me there's a tacit lemma lurking in the background here:  If $(r,s)=(r,t)=1$, then $(r,st)=1$.

Comment: I see... let me add a reference to that result :)

Comment: Knowing the fact that I mentioned in the first comment, the proof can be done in a line: $$\gcd(a,b)=d\implies \gcd({a\over d},{b\over d})=1\implies \gcd\big(({a\over d})^2,({b\over d})^2\big)=1\implies \gcd(a^2,b^2)=d^2$$

Comment: That looks neat indeed!

Answer (score 2):

I'll use the notation of Michael's answer.

Since $g_2\mid a^2$, $g_2\mid b^2$, $g_1\mid a$ and $g_1\mid b$, there are integers $p,q,r,s$ such that:

$$a^2 = g_2p, \ b^2=g_2q, \ a=g_1r, \ b=g_1s \ ,$$

with $gcd(p,q)=1$ and $gcd(r,s)=1$. Manipulating those expressions, is easy to get that $r^2q=s^2p$ and, by Euclid's lemma, $r^2\mid p$ and $p\mid r^2$ thus $p=r^2$ (assuming positive integers), similarly, $q=s^2$ so finally

$$g_1^2 = \frac{a^2}{r^2}=\frac{g_2p}{r^2} = g_2$$

Here I use that if $gcd(r,s)=1$, then $gcd(r^2,s^2)=1$. This is much easier to prove than the general case so my reasoning is not circular.

Answer (score -1):

Hint (for the easy direction): Suppose that $g_1=\gcd(a,b)$ and $g_2=\gcd(a^2,b^2)$.  Since $g_1\mid a$ and $g_1\mid b$, then $g_1^2\mid a^2$ and $g_1^2\mid b^2$.  Therefore, by the definition of the greatest common divisor, $g_1^2\mid g_2$.